# How to toggle a status in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to use localStorage for the first time to toggle a dark mode status. I am struggling to get it to work when refreshing and changing pages.

Any help with my code in order to understand my errors would be appreciated.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('status')) {
      localStorage.setItem('status', 'light');
    }

dmToggle.onclick = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('status') === 'light') {
    makeDark();
    localStorage.setItem('status', 'dark');
  } else if (localStorage.getItem('status') === 'dark') {
    makeLight();
    localStorage.setItem('status', 'light');
  }
}
```

Currently status only toggles after the second click, and page reverts to light mode on refresh or page switch.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: The code provided does not have initial calls of ```makeDark();``` or ```makeLight();```. Are there any but in onclick?

Comment: @Syperia The makeDark/Light functions are defined, but this is their first call. The page is default light (defined in css). 

The issue with the code does not seem to be the functions, but instead the setting & getting of the status in localStorage.

Comment: @TomYemm the question was about initial calls. It is expected that you will do initialisation like

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('status')) {
      localStorage.setItem('status', 'light');
 } else {
localStorage.getItem('status') === 'light' ? makeLight() : makeDark();
}
```

Comment: @syperia 

`
dmToggle.onclick = () => {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('status')) {
    localStorage.setItem('status', 'light');
  } else if (localStorage.getItem('status') === 'light') {
    makeDark();
    localStorage.setItem('status', 'dark');
  } else {
    makeLight();
    localStorage.setItem('status', 'light');
  }
}
`

Reformatted to the above, but identical results to my initial code.

Comment: @TomYemm: Can you update the question to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing when you debug?

Comment: @David https://jsfiddle.net/tk2q895m/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (localStorage.getItem("status") === "dark") {
  makeDark();
} else {
  makeLight();
}

dmToggle.onclick = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('status') === 'light') {
    makeDark();
    localStorage.setItem('status', 'dark');
  } else {
    makeLight();
    localStorage.setItem('status', 'light');
  }
}
```

Solved!

When debugging I noted that the 'status' was correct on page load, but was not being initialised.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

This is the working version of what you're trying to achieve:

```js
const THEME_KEY = 'status';

function getThemeFromStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem(THEME_KEY);
}

function setThemeToStorage(themeName) {
    localStorage.setItem(THEME_KEY, themeName);
}

function setTheme(themeName) {
  setThemeToStorage(themeName);
  document.querySelector('#targetEl').classList.value = themeName;
}

// Init. Default to 'light'
setTheme(getThemeFromStorage() || 'light');

document.querySelector('#button').onclick = () => {
    setTheme(getThemeFromStorage() === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.dark {
  background: #000;
}

.light {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="targetEl"></div>
<button id="button">Toggle theme</button>
```

You may try it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Syperia/auz9cwfj/52/)

Comment: This is probably a perfectly working example of what OP tries to achieve. However, what will the OP learn from this? What did you do to help him **understand** his errors?

Comment: What specifically wasn't working in the code shown in the question?  How does this code correct that specific problem?

Comment: The code shown in question lacked initialisation. The code in answer provides an implementation with it.